# how to replace value in a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script to alter the few values in file `sysctl.conf` in `/etc directory`

If variable value is less than that then it should alter the value to below given value

For example:

`sysctl.conf` file contains the following lines (the terms in parentheses are my own comments and are not in the actual file):

```
kernel.shmall = 5194304 (more than 4194304 so it should leave it as it is)
kernel.shmmax = 2147483648 (it is equal to 2147483648 so it should leave it as it is)
kernel.msgmni = 124 (it is less than 1024 so it should alter the value to 1024)
```

expecting output is

```
kernel.shmall = 5194304 
kernel.shmmax = 2147483648
kernel.msgmni = 1024
```

This is my script I am preparing to replace `kernel.shmall` if value is less than or equal to `4194303`

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `cat /etc/sysctl.conf|fgrep kernel.shmall` | while read kernel.shmall
if [ "kernel.shmall" -le 4194303 ]; then
    kernel.shmall = 4194304
fi`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And same you can use for other properties.

Also if property not exist then you can do like this

```
if grep -o "kernel.shmall" /etc/sysctl.conf > /dev/null
then
     oldvalue=$(grep kernel.shmall /etc/sysctl.conf | awk '{ print $3 }')

     if [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ]
     then
        sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
     fi
else
     echo "kernel.shmall=" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
     sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
fi
```

Comment: @user3541225 i give you only example here for`kernel.shmall` but you can do use same command for other properties with respective values.

Comment: out put of grep kernel.shmall /emblocal/sysctl.conf2| awk '{ print $1}'
kernel.shmall=4194304
I am trying to delimit =

Comment: @user3541225 It seems correct...have you getting expected result?

Comment: achived it by following
grep -v '^#' /emblocal/sysctl.conf|grep kernel.shmall|sed 's/=/ /g'| awk '{ print $2}'

Comment: if grep -o "kernel.shmall" /etc/sysctl.conf > /dev/null
then
     oldvalue=$(grep -v '^#' /etc/sysctl.conf|grep kernel.shmall|sed 's/=/ /g'| awk '{ print $2}')
     if [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ]
     then
        sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
     fi
else
     echo "kernel.shmall=" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
     sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
fi

is throwing error
 [: -lt: unary operator expected
because as there is no variable "kernel.shmall" in file. How to add it as above script is not adding when there is no variable

Comment: we achived almost. But i am stuck up at when there is no kernel.shmall parameter in file then it is throwing error.
`[: argument expected`
code failing at
`if [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ]`
 because there is no parameter "kernel.shmall"

Comment: Can you guide me throgh to achive this one
`if grep -o "kernel.shmall" /etc/sysctl.conf > /dev/null
      2 then
      3      oldvalue=$(grep -v '^#' /etc/sysctl.conf|grep kernel.shmall|sed 's/=/ /g'| awk '{ print $2}')
      4
      5      if [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ]
      6      then
      7         sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
      8      fi
      9 else
     10      echo "kernel.shmall=" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
     11      sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /etc/sysctl.conf
     12 fi`
code is failing at line5 as no"kernel.shmall"

Comment: Can you help me in adding paramater which is not there also

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a clearer way of getting the values from your file is:

```
value=$(grep kernel.shmall /etc/sysctl.conf | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

Then, to replace the value in the file:

```
sed -i "/kernel.shmall =/ s/$value/4194304/" /etc/sysctl.conf
```